# Can't focus or type on email field

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform

The weird thing I noticed today working on a website is that in footer section of site I have a quick contact form which I cant focus on email field in Firefox, in chrome it works as it suppose to, but I have no idea what's wrong with it in firefox, and I didn't really have the time or will to check it in IE too.

the website is on Drupal and the form is webform module's block. as far as I know there is no javascript file specified on the fields and one thing I noticed is that if I inspect the email field and change the type to something else, it works!

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Your webform is definitely using JavaScript.

Comment: well I couldn't see any errors regarding that, but thanks for the hint, I try to look for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a CSS issue.

In your CSS, you have this selector `.block-webform input.email`. Just add `height: auto;` to it.

Actually you can type normally on the field, you can not just see what you typed due to CSS height limitation caused by limiting the height using this CSS property `height: 1.8em;`.

I'm not able to tell you the lines' numbers because you compressed the CSS files :), but I believe you can easily find them.

Answer (score 1):

One of your classes in the input is causing the trouble. Look at the following classes : email form-text form-email required

The text is being entered it is just not visible. Once you remove the classes from the input then you can see the text/email address entered.